# How to upload image to redmine server?

Tags: ios, objective-c, file-upload, redmine

I tried sending the details(referring this link http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_api) using the below code(the url is mylocalst:portnumber/uploads.json).But I am getting the 500 error message.What is the meaning of request body as file content While uploading the image to server?Can anyone please provide me some information regarding this?

```
  ` NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[dataObj length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
request.timeoutInterval = 60;

[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"application/octet-stream" forHTTPHeaderField:@"CONTENT_TYPE"];
[request setValue:@"my api key" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Redmine-API-Key"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:dataObj];
 NSURLConnection *conn=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
if (conn)
{
    receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init] ;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you passing correct key values i mean dataObj

Comment: I just sent the image data as request body.In the above link they have written as request body as file content.                                                 POST /uploads.json
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
...
(request body is the file content)

# 201 response
{"upload":{"token":"7167.ed1ccdb093229ca1bd0b043618d88743"}}

Comment: Not understanding what to send as file content

Comment: ask ur web service team

Comment: I am using redline server

Comment: sorry..RedMine server